# What if I have to handle a primary key that's equal to String.Empty in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, null, primary-key

I have a Table in my VB.NET code that map an alias with his real name, with alias as a key.

Problem is that I have to handle the case of alias being an empty string and that causes an exception because `String.Empty` equals `Nothing` in VB.NET

How am I supposed to handle this case? Is there a way I could handle this without editing the underlying DB definition from something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [tablename] (
[alias] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[name]  NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([alias] ASC)
);
```

to something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [tablename] (
[alias] NVARCHAR (100) NULL, UNIQUE
[name]  NVARCHAR (100) NULL
);
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad design to me. What happens when you have two people with the same alias?

Comment: It simply never happens, I need this table only to normalize a list of hardware producers to their stardard name (like 'nvidia corp' to simply 'nVidia', or 'HP printer' to 'HP') so is built in a way to avoid those kind of problems (yes our suppliers likes to give us problems, also there is some design problem in the db, pretty sure about it)

Comment: And what happens when you have two blank aliases? It's fundamentally bad design. You need an artificial key, typically an identity column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, `string.Empty = Nothing` equals `True`, `string.Empty Is Nothing` equals `False`.

[Fiddle Here.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/npNgGI)

Don't use `=` to test strings for equality with [`Nothing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx).

Comment: Sadly I have little control on how the code check the constraints, cause most of the code is autogenerated and from what I can see everything is handled by the `SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)` method that seems to raise a ConstraintException for the empty string

Comment: @Foma, well, either you need to change the comparison or what you are comparing.